# Como converter arquivos binários em String de maneira segura?

Tags: ruby, arquivo, binary

Sistema Operacional: Windows 10;

Versão do Ruby: 2.2.1;

Aplicação do Servidor: Apache 2 (mod_cgi);

Devo criar um script que leia um arquivo, converta o mesmo em texto e após um possível processamento, envie o resultado para o usuário.

O processo atual funciona muito bem para arquivos de texto (html, plain, css etc...), mas quando o assunto é binários (pdf, jpg, png etc...) os arquivos saem sempre "ilegíveis" ou corrompidos (no caso de JPEGs), uma vez que o navegador consegue montar a imagem mas ela não é a original no servidor.

O código utilizado até o momento é o seguinte:

```
mime_type = 'image/jpeg'
file = File.open(File.dirname(__FILE__) + 'imagem.jpg', "rb")
head = "Status: 200 OK\nContent-Type: #{mime_type}\nConnection: close\nContent-Length: #{file.size()}\n\n"
body = file.read()
print head + body
```

Alguém sabe uma maneira segura de ler arquivos binários no Windows para retornar ao cliente?

Answer (score 0):

"puts" adiciona um CR/LF no final de cada linha, como você não estava especificando o tamanho do binário no cabeçalho o outro lado está aceitando esses dois bytes a mais como parte do conteúdo, o que obviamente o corrompe. Use "print" em vez de puts.

Comment: Testei as soluções citadas. A imagem ainda não é mostrada. No entanto agora, ao baixá-la, o arquivo resultado tem o exato tamanho do arquivo original. (Código atualizado na pergunta)

Comment: Se usar "print head" e "STDOUT.write(body)" muda alguma coisa? Estou achando que o "print" e "puts" estão traduzindo algum caractere tipo CRLF ou Control-Z.

Comment: Continua corrompida. Pela minha análise o arquivo resultante tem o mesmo tamanho em bytes do original, mas tem uma linha a mais. (no caso desta imagem específica) No caso do PDF o arquivo tem o mesmo tamanho porém trinta linhas a mais.

Comment: Descobri que a bobagem acontece provavelmente no `file.read()`. Pois tentei salvar o que foi lido a um novo arquivo e este novo arquivo estava corrompido e maior do que o original.

Comment: Pode ser então que File.read() esteja tentando aplicar um encoding. Tem o método IO.binread(nome) que talvez valha a pena tentar

Comment: Já tentei. O resultado é o mesmo. Eu creio que o `File.read()` utiliza o `IO.binread`.